# Mongoose.findOne always returning null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem, this is the first time that I've encountered this problem. For some reason when calling the `mongoose.findOne` function on my model it always returns null.

Below is my following code.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    password: String,
    email: String
});

var userModel = mongoose.model("user", userSchema, "user");

module.exports.userModel = userModel;
```

When creating my model I give I override mongoose's standard behaviour of pluralising model names.

Where I need to query is when I need to make sure that the email that the user wants to use is not already in use by another user. To do this I wrote the following code.

```
function CheckRegisterInfo(email, callback) {
    //first check if email is taken
    UserModel.findOne({'email': email}, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            callback(2);
        }else if (!docs)  {
            callback(0);
        }else {
            callback(1);
        }
    });
};
```

My DB does have data so there is no reason why it would be returning null as far as I can tell. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is inside *err*?

Comment: Nothing, there is no error, it simply returns null for docs.

Comment: You can try to insert the data using this model, and see where the data is inserted to check that your code searches in the right place.

Comment: @edtech `db.user.insert({email: "email1@email1.com", password: "password"})` in the mongo shell works and the document gets inserted into the `user` collection so the problem is with mongoose.

Comment: @A.Catchpole what is UserModel in your second fragment of code? Maybe you have to call UserModel.userModel.findOne(...) ?

Also, how about trying to insert the data using mongoose and your model?

Comment: I have userModel set to the userModel variable in exports. `var UserModel = require('../models/userModel.js').userModel;` inserting data works when creating an instance of the userModel called newUser and passing in the data to save before calling `.save()` on newUser object.

Comment: Try to create a new item from Mongoose using this code: var u = new UserModel({email:'email@email1.com', password: "password"}); u.save(function(err) { });

Comment: Edited my comment to include what I missed. I'm already creating a new object to save my data and that works but the problem is querying. Saving data works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem, it was to do with passing the correct variable into the function. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: Do you mind sharing how you fixed the issue? Thanks.